# Change event triggered by change of cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I want to hide columns with value 0 in range G4:FC4
The cell can take values 0 (in that case the columns should be hidden) or 1 (in that case they should be visible). The value 0 or 1 is formula based and depends on the drop down input value in cell D2.
When I change the value in D2 manually the macro works fine, but when I use the drop down box it doesn't. Please find below my code. Any advice?

Many thanks

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim r As Range
Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Sheets("P_MM6").Range("G4:FC4").Cells
        c.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        If c.Value = 1 Then
            c.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: What does it mean "it doesn't"? E.g. - false result, error, does not run at all, the electricity in the city stops?

Comment: What kind of DropDown do you use?

Comment: @EvR An excellent point - I have just tested, and can confirm that using a "Data Validation" drop-down works, but a "Combo Box" Form Control with a Cell link does not

Comment: @Chronocidal - if you want to use a form control drop down, you can get it work by calling the same code that is in your worksheet_change event. If you make one procedure, you can call it via worksheet change or combo box change.

Comment: combo box change works... thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Changing manually vs drop-down should not matter, except if perhaps somewhere else in your code events are being disabled and not turned back on, or maybe calculations are set to manual and thus do not create a change in the formula value, so, even though the code fires, the column values don't change.

That said, the code below will help you because it will not try to hide/unhide on *every* cell change, but only when D2 changes.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If target.address = "$D$2" Then

        Dim c As Range
        For Each c In Sheets("P_MM6").Range("G4:FC4").Cells
            c.EntireColumn.Hidden = c.Value = 0
        Next c

     End If

End Sub
```

Also make sure that calculations are set to automatic and they are not being turned off somewhere in your code and also that events are not being disabled and not turned back on somewhere else in the code.

If all that doesn't help, put a break point on the `Worksheet_Change` line of code and change the cell via drop-down and see what happens.